# How can I tell if a path is explicit (i.e. not relative to an implicit drive or directory)?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check whether a given path is an explicit path that unambiguously specifies a particular location. So, I want to rule out paths like:

```
file
directory
directory\file
C:file
\directory\file
```

I want to allow:

```
C:\file
C:\directory
C:\directory\file
\\server\share\file
\\server\share\directory\file
```

The `Path.IsRooted` method almost does what I need, but it returns true for the last two examples above (`C:file` and `\directory\file`), which respectively imply a current directory and current drive.

Is there another method I can use? Note that I don't care whether the file/directory actually exists.

Comment: @SamIam: I do not like them, Sam I am. Seriously, though, I'm looking for something in the framework. I hate to duplicate something that already exists - which surely it must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into source code one can find the actual implementation of `Path.IsPathRooted` to be like this:

```
public static bool IsPathRooted(string path)
{
    if (path != null)
    {
        Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(path);
        int length = path.Length;
        if ((length >= 1 && (path[0] == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar || path[0] == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
            || (length >= 2 && path[1] == Path.VolumeSeparatorChar))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now it becomes evident how to adjust it to suit your needs - you can define a new method and slightly change the conditions (and maybe refactor them a little - they do not look very good):

```
if ((length >= 1 && ((path[0] == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar && path[1] == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) || path[0] == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
    || (length >= 3 && path[1] == Path.VolumeSeparatorChar && path[2] == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
```

Comment: I like your thinking. I just wish there was an existing function I could call, to avoid re-inventing (a possibly inferior) wheel.

Comment: @GaryMcGill, actually this is what I was hoping for waiting for ILSpy to load data - that `IsPathRooted` calls some other function which parameters can be tweaked, or something like this. Reality appeared to be somewhat different.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Path.GetFullPath()` and compare the result to the original string:

```
bool IsPathAbsolute(string path)
{
    return Path.GetFullPath(path) == path;
}
```

Comment: That however would fall foul of any differences in case, or use of "short names" such as "DOCUME~1" for "Documents and Settings"...

Comment: I started doing that, but then realised that the case of the path or the use of short names is not relevant to the problem - it's only relevant to this particular solution. So I think a comment here is best.